split long hex string into 8 byte segments starting from the END
If I run this code, I get segments starting from the beginning. I need this code for little-endian purposes so I have to reverse the order since I will be pushing bytes on the stack and the last bytes at the end are actuall first. The order is correct. The issue is that if I segment them by 8 bytes, it starts at the beginning. The last segment is not 8 bytes, it is 3 so I want to start from the end. Any ideas?
import sys
from textwrap import wrap
string = sys.argv[1]
data = string.encode().hex()
value=bytes.fromhex(data)
value=value[::-1]
s = bytes.hex(value)
#print(s)
print(wrap(s, width=8))

To run it, its just python3 this_script.py "this is a long string".
Currently, the output looks like this:
['676e6972', '74732067', '6e6f6c20', '61207369', '20736968', '74']

I want it to start at the end, from 74.
Here is what I would like output to look like.
['67', '6e697274', '7320676e', '6f6c2061', '20736920', '73696874']


hi example input and expected output please.

.hex() splits them up for you with the right parameters.
string = 'this is a long string'
value = string.encode()[::-1].hex(sep=' ', bytes_per_sep=4).split()
print(value)

Output:
['67', '6e697274', '7320676e', '6f6c2061', '20736920', '73696874']

